# How do i put a $ before a database tag

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I try to make a website with an account system, but now i am stuck.

I already tries to do it with this code `<?php echo "<p>$</p>"$userRow['username']; ?>`
what i want to have is that there will be something like this $USERNAME and that has to transform into the thing that i put into my config file.
 `$daan0605 = ('CoOwner'); $mohagames205 = ('HeadCreator');` Sorry that i dont know all the terms yet,

but i hope you guys can help me :).

Comment: try like this  `"$".$userRow['username'];`

Comment: You forgot `.` in `<?php echo "<p>$</p>"$userRow['username']; ?>` use like this `<?php echo '$'.$userRow['username']; ?>`

Comment: Hpy eid, you should be prompt after asking any question to get answer quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Variable variables**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) is what you're looking for. In that case you would simply do,

```
<?php echo $$userRow['username']; ?>
```

So if `$userRow['username']` outputs `daan0605` and `$daan0605 = 'CoOwner';`, then the above statement would output `CoOwner`.